# Dozer Mapping Ignore Hibernate Lazy Loading - Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, cxf, dozer

I am using Apache CXF with Spring and Dozer Mapper to convert DTOs (Database Objects) in to models. For **Hibernate** side I have enabled `lazy="extra"` and `lazy="true"` for mapping and which works fine hibernate loads child whenever respective getter methods are called. But when I convert DTO using dozer mapper it calls getter methods of all the child object in some case it was not necessary but in some it is not necessary. Is there any way by using which I can reduce overheads.

Answer (score 2):

> Fetch(load) child's always in every call results to heavy process and
>   unnecessary data to persist. So instead of doing this always fetch
>   data as lazy and initialize child's model whenever there is
>   need. This is the best way to fetch data.

Answer (score 2):

If you convert entities to [DTOs](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=427), you have two options:

- [do not use lazy collections](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=645)
- [ignore the collections](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/exclude.html) when serializing, if you don't want them in the output